# Using Yeoman build I'm getting "Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a"

Tags: angularjs

When I run yeoman build and then go to my web app I'm getting the following error

Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this related issue https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/646